# Certificate to pfx with private key...?

Tags: .net, certificate, x509certificate, private-key, pfx

I've certificate which I can install from dongle.
When I view that installed certificate using IE. It shows me it has private key as below.

[image]

But when I try to export that certificate to .pfx using my c# code, the private key is null.

below is my code for exporting certificate to pfx, where private key always null

```
public static bool ExportCertificateToPFX(string certificateSerialNumber, string pxfFilepath, StoreName storeName, StoreLocation location)
{
    bool success = false;

    X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, location);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, certificateSubject, true);

    if (certs != null && certs.Count > 0)
    {
        //BELOW CONDITION ALWAYS FALSE
        if (certs[0].HasPrivateKey)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(certs[0].PrivateKey.ToString());
        }
        byte[] data = certs[0].Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "KALPESH");
        //HERE WRITE "data" TO "pxfFilepath" FILE
    }
    store.Close();


    return success;
}
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: In all likelihood, the dongle does not allow extraction of the private key.

Comment: Ok, Phylogenesis in that case, is that any possibility, I can read taht private key and certificate directly from dongle with my code.

Comment: @ManishJain The normal reason for blocking access will be for security reasons. Your dongle is there to sign something when you have the dongle. If someone could insert it and pull off the private key it holds then it loses that security. It becomes 'something you know' rather than 'something you have'.

Comment: Yes, you should use, PKCS#11 interface or Cryptoapi's custom csp to access the key with in the dongle. What token are you you using? What's your programming language?

Comment: @Raj I'm using c# winform app. I've just go with Cryptoapi, but for use that I need token's PKCS#11. But how to get it.

Comment: Who is your Token/hardware vendor?

Comment: @Raj, I read your previous comment where you asked me about programming language and dongle vendor, only reason I didn't reply about Token vendor name because may be that's legal or not to take private key out of token, rather I have authorized person to use that token.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilites (starting from less-probable):

1. Certificate's private key uses unsupported by .NET key storage provider to store the keys. For example, Microsoft KSP or its own.
2. There is no private key at all. You can run `certutil -store` with appropriate parameters (depending on where the certificate is installed) to verify whether there is a private key. Also this command gives you an answer if the key uses unsupported key storage.